# SVD function returns matrices with not compatible dimensions

Tags: python, linear-algebra, svd

let us consider following matrix

```
2 4
1 3
0 0
0 0
```

creation of this matrix in python and corresponding singular value decomposition can be  done in python in  a simple  way

```
A =np.array([[2,4],[1,3],[0,0],[0,0]])
u,s,v =np.linalg.svd(A)
```

when i typed  dimensions of corresponding matrix, i got following

```
print(u)
print(np.diag(s))
print(v)

[-0.57604844  0.81741556  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          1.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          1.        ]]
[[5.4649857  0.        ]
 [0.         0.36596619]]
[[-0.40455358 -0.9145143 ]
 [-0.9145143   0.40455358]]
```

therefore following code for reconstructing original matrix does not work

```
print(u.dot(np.dot(np.diag(s),v)))
```

how can i fix this problem? thanks in advance

Comment: s matrix should be 4x2, but the lower 2x2 part is null. We don't need to compute it. You can either complete s with 2 additional null rows, or ignore last two columns of u, that's a more economic representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the formal definition of the SVD, the shape of `s` should be `(4, 2)`. However NumPy's routine returns an array of singular values of shape `(2,)`. Furthermore, `np.diag()` doesn't know anything about how big `s` "should" be in the full decomposition. It just takes an array of shape `(n,)` and returns a 2D array of shape `(n, n)`. So your inner product ends up with shapes `(4, 4) * (2, 2) * (2, 2)`, which of course fails because sizes of the first product don't make sense.

To fix this, just construct an array of the correct size for `s`:

```
>>> u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(A)
>>> true_s = np.zeros((u.shape[1], v.shape[0]))
>>> true_s[:s.size, :s.size] = np.diag(s)
>>> np.allclose(u.dot(true_s).dot(v), A)
True
```